# wamp not working although its green

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

I installed WAMP server and it's icon is **green** but I have not access to the `localhost` in my browser.

I tried to fix it by doing some works like:

- Changeing the port number in `httpd.conf` in lines 62 and 63 from `80` to `8080` and restarted WAMP.
- Then checking the port `80` and it was not in use.
- Uninstalling `IIS` from my system.
- Running `netsh winsock reset` command in cmd (Run as Admin) and restarted my pc.

It is very strange for me that any of the above workarounds could not solve the problem.

**Edit:**

1. My wamp server is `v2.5.x64`.
2. When I want to access `localhost`, the browser says:

   > webpage is not available
3. There is no error in **apache error log** and **php erro log** files.
4. When I try to open `MySQL` log using `WAMP` icon, it says:

   > Cannot find `c:\wamp\logs\mysql.log` file
5. There is no error for `MySQL` in `Windows Event Viewer`, but I can't find Apache here.

Comment: Can you start by telling us **edit your question** `) What verison of WAMPServer 2) What __actually happens__ when you access localhost 3) Are there any errors in the _Apache log_ 4) Are there any errors in the _MYSQL log_ 5) Are there any errors in the _Windows Event Viewer_

Comment: @ThomasRollet  there is no error in log files.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the question is edited now. check it again please.

Comment: @mama23n What apache access log says ?

Comment: What happens when you use this address in the browser address bar `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @ThomasRollet maybe I should say that wamp was not working after I installed it yesterday but today Strangely it was fixed!! but again its not working. I say it because every line in apache access log is about last time that I worked with wamp when it was OK and after that there is no any line in it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly OMG !!!! its Ok with this address ! thank you very much.
but why??

Comment: You changed the Listening port from 80 ( the default used by all browsers ) to 8080. So you have to add it to each URL manually. I would suggest working out why you needed to use 8080 and go back to port 80 if at all possible

Comment: have u checked the loopback address instead of `localhost`? (http://127.0.0.1)

Comment: whenever there's question of whether the browser is redirecting to search URL, i'd like to test with `telnet`.  so, bring up a command promopt and issue: `telnet localhost 80` or `telnet localhost 8080`.  if the apache is bound to your network IP, then issue: `telnet <network_ip> 80` or `telnet <network_ip> 8080`.  see if any would work.  the successful one would indicate to you which port apache is bound to.  if it exists in windows,`netstat` helps.  but once you are sure you have the connection info right, then you can try to hit it with the browser (try as many kinds as you can install.)